# Laravel Queued job execution with delay

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-queue

I am using Laravel queued jobs to simply create a copy of my tables in JSON format and delete the created file afterwards. Here is my handle method:

```
public function handle()
{
    unlink($this->file);
}
```

The code works fine as long as I dispatch the file right after response:

```
DeleteCreatedFiles::dispatchAfterResponse(/* File path */);
```

However I want to keep the file for some time before deleting so I used this code:

```
DeleteCreatedFiles::dispatch(/* file path */)
        ->delay(now()->addSeconds(30));
```

The trouble is that the job is never executed no matter how much I wait. I tried using the telescope and it keeps showing the **pending** status. Please help me figure out why this is happening.
Thanks!

Comment: How do you execute the queue?

Comment: Through Job::dispatch() method.

Comment: I executed the job directly

Comment: erm.. what is your queue driver in your env?

Comment: @Faheem-maker does my answer helped you out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first you have to set the queue driver in `.env` file not to be `sync`

since if your job is delayed, it has to be queued. so **sync** option shouldn't be used

2. [then create a queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#driver-prerequisites)

based on the queue driver (like database,redis, ...), you can make a queue.

3. run a worker:

- for single thread run:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

or listen-aware worker on development :

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

- for [supervised queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration)
- for multi-thread you can use [laravel-horizon package](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon)

Comment: Just a comment: while developing is convenient to use `php artisan queue:listen` to make workers aware of changes. Otherwise you have to restart the worker on every change done

Comment: thanks @Lucano . you are right. I am gonna add it to m answer

Comment: So you have to start a queue worker before the job will execute?

Comment: sure, in order to execute the jobs, there should be a worker running to handle the jobs